# why progressbar works separately from countdown

Tags: javascript, progress-bar, setinterval, countdown

I want to create progress bar countdown.
But the problem is that decimals don't change like 10 9 8 7 .. simultaniously.

this is html :

```
<progress id="prg" value ="0" max="10"></progress>
<p id="counting">10</p>
```

This is my js script :

```
var reverse_count = 10;
var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById('prg').value = 10 - --reverse_count;
    if(reverse_count <= 0) {
        clearInterval (downloadTimer); 
        document.getElementById('counting').innerHTML = reverse_count;
    }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to take `document.getElementById('counting').innerHTML = reverse_count;` out of the if statement, like so:

```js
var reverse_count = 10;

var downloadTimer = setInterval(function() {
  document.getElementById('prg').value = 10 - --reverse_count;
  if (reverse_count <= 0) {
    clearInterval(downloadTimer);
  }
  document.getElementById('counting').innerHTML = reverse_count;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<progress id="prg" value="0" max="10"></progress>
<p id="counting">10</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just added the right statement in the wrong place. The update of the countdown label should also be done each time the interval callback is executed, as you do with the update of the `<progress>` `value`, not only once just before calling `clearInterval`:

```js
const progressBar = document.getElementById('progressBar');
const countdownLabel = document.getElementById('countdownLabel');

let countdown = 10;

const downloadTimer = setInterval(() => {
  // This is executed multiple times until the interval is cleared:
  countdownLabel.innerHTML = --countdown;
  progressBar.value = 10 - countdown;
  
  if (countdown <= 0) {
    // This is only executed once when the countdown gets to 0:
    clearInterval(downloadTimer); 
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<progress id="progressBar" value ="0" max="10"></progress>
<p id="countdownLabel">10</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code the countdown updates iff `reverse_count <= 0`.

```js
var reverse_count = 10;
var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
  document.getElementById('prg').value = 10 - --reverse_count;
  document.getElementById('counting').innerHTML = reverse_count;
  if(reverse_count <= 0) {
    clearInterval (downloadTimer);
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<progress id="prg" value ="0" max="10"></progress>
<p id="counting">10</p>
```